# Create an expiring PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is there a way to create a PDF that is:

- Password protected
- Can not be printed
- Can not be viewed after a certain date/time?

Comment: Similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/37216/restrict-print-copies-on-a-pdf Conclusion: not easy, but maybe with Adobe Digital Editions.

Comment: Yeah, I found that post before I posted my question.  I was hoping there is a 3rd party solution.

Comment: @outsideblasts - that was going to be my first suggestion too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Adobe is trialing a new service that might just fit your needs - [Adobe's "Protect an Adobe PDF File" service](https://createpdf.adobe.com/cgi-feeder.pl/ppdf_faq#whatAllowMe):

> **What is the Protect an Adobe PDF File
>   service?**
>
> Protect an Adobe PDF File is
>   an online service that allows you to
>   protect your Adobe PDF documents in
>   powerful new ways. Once your PDF files
>   have been protected using the Protect
>   an Adobe PDF File service, you retain
>   complete control over who can access
>   your files and what actions the users
>   of your documents may take. You even
>   have the ability to modify allowable
>   actions or revoke access to protected
>   Adobe PDF files altogether after you
>   have distributed your documents.
>
> **What exactly does Protect an Adobe PDF
>   File allow me to do?**
>
> The Protect an
>   Adobe PDF File service allows you to
>   apply persistent usage rights settings
>   to the PDF file itself. For example,
>   you can:
>
> - Specify exactly who can open a protected Adobe PDF file, regardless
>     of how the file is received,
> - Restrict the types of actions that users can take (such as no
>     printing, no copying, or no redlining
>     and commenting),
> - Specify a time period during which the file can be accessed by
>     users,
> - Revoke access to copies of the document even after you have
>     distributed such copies, and
> - Track events related to the copies you have distributed, such as
>     when they were accessed, who accessed
>     them, and more.
>
> **How much does the service cost?**
>
> The Protect an Adobe PDF File service
>   is currently in beta. During the
>   initial beta period, it is available
>   at no extra cost to Create Adobe PDF
>   Online subscribers. Subscription rates
>   and other charges may be applied at
>   the end of this period.
>
> The Protect an Adobe PDF File service
>   is also available now to trial users
>   of Create Adobe PDF Online.

Looks like right now you have to be a part of [Adobe's online PDF creation service](https://createpdf.adobe.com/).

Answer (score 3):

No.

There are ways to have restrictions in PDF files such as printing, however, I have not seen a single method that cannot be bypassed by someone who knows what they are doing.

For the person who downvoted me, I wanted to add-

Pretty much any and every DRM service has been hacked or cracked at some point... Are you saying I couldn't load a PDF in a virtual machine and simply take a screenshot from the host, or even get a camera against my screen?...

Comment: Agree the answer is "NO"

If you can see it the screen - you can print it and you can save it.