# How can I expire a video after a date?

Tags: video

My question should explain all by itself and these are my requirements:

- I have few videos which I shoot myself and share them. I do not want
  any other restrictions on them other than that it should **not** be playable
  after a particular date or time.
- I would like to stick with popular codec and container format so that
  the viewers can view the video file in their computer or mobile (I am
  yet to make them and hence I think I have some control on the codecs 
  and containers).
- I do not mind playing it through an application, like wrapping a video in an executable provided, the process of making that executable is free of cost.
- I do not mind the viewers sharing this video with others once I can make
  them expire.

I have searched this site and general Google search as well. But I couldn't find one.

Comment: There is a dvd format for that purpose that does it on a chemical basis i think. That fact could support the theory that there is no reliable software solution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexplay

Comment: Any file on a user's hdd can be converted with enough work.  Once that happens you have no control over being able to disable the video.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I explain why DRM cannot work?](http://superuser.com/questions/14224/how-can-i-explain-why-drm-cannot-work), [Is there a license / royalty free DRM available for protecting and distributing content?](http://superuser.com/questions/54236/is-there-a-license-royalty-free-drm-available-for-protecting-and-distributing)

Comment: [How to STOP people from DOWNLOADING an online video for OFFLINE PLAYBACK](http://superuser.com/questions/667974/how-to-stop-people-from-downloading-an-online-video-for-offline-playback?lq=1)

Comment: Basically, if you could create this in an unbreakable way, you'd be a billionaire. Give up now.  ;)

Comment: @TheUser1024, you could just copy the DVD to get around that 'protection'!

Comment: @DaveRook: I would think they have some means to prevent that. I have no idea though. The best quote on the subject was an answer to the question "how do i protect my dvd?": "Maintain a good relationship with your customer or target audience!". To me that is the ultimate answer, you can always point a camcorder at the screen.

Comment: in the first bullet point should it be 'other than that it *not* should be playable after a certain date'? Or are you trying to embargo them.