# DRM a Custom video

Tags: video-encoding, drm

I have a video which is a matroska file (mkv). I wish to DRM protect the video to stop users from re-encoding the video or editing it.

Meaning original video gets DRM:  user can download video, watch, delete but when using a program to re-encode they cannot.

The main question is, is this achievable? And if so has anyone had a chance to do this?

Comment: No offense, but if the MPAA cannot stop people from pirating movies I doubt you are going to. You may want to add a "within reason" clause to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I explain why DRM cannot work?](http://superuser.com/questions/14224/how-can-i-explain-why-drm-cannot-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a video file to be protected with DRM, then it must have a participating video player that controls what the recipient can do with the file.

The video player will check whether the recipient has a license to play the video, and if so, decrypt and play the file.  This prevents copying and re-encoding as the video player does not provide these features.

So the video would need to be distributed via a channel that provides DRM, such as Amazon or iTunes.

It isn't possible to have a file that is playable via a normal video player and also have that file uneditable.  If a video file can be played, it can be transcoded and edited.