# File Encryption

Tags: windows, encryption, usb-flash-drive, dvd

I want to send a client a disc (DVD) version where files can not be moved off of the DVD onto a computer. Is there a simple way to encrypt a disc so that no files can be moved off onto a computer?

I've tried to use Windows EFS but it loses encryption when I copy the files to a DVD, I've thought about formatting a flash drive using NFTS and then copy the files on there. I've heard that will keep it from losing encryption. Is there any other way to achieve This?

Comment: "I want to send a client a disc (DVD) version where files can not be moved off of the DVD onto a computer." - This is not possible.  If the client can read the file they can create a copy of the file.  If you use EFS you would have to supply the capability to decrypt the files, which makes encrypting the files to prevent them from being copied, sort of pointless.  Trying to prevent them from being copied isn't the purpose of EFS or Bitlocker.  Encryption is used to prevent unauthorized access to the files, and only allow those with the ability to decrpyt the files, access to the files.

Comment: No. See [How can I explain why DRM cannot work?](https://superuser.com/q/14224)

Comment: Sony tried to implement this a few years ago by installing rootkit software to prevent copying on any PC where the disc was loaded. They were rightly criticised vehemently for doing this and in any case it was very easy to circumvent.

Comment: Anything that is decrypt-able as Ramhound mentioned, can be copied over once in the un-encrypted state (reading the file), there is a possibility or using ACLs or advanced MAC controls but on windows this is a royal PITA,  and requires a decent level of knowledge on both parties part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.  In order to read the files, the user *must* have access to them.  If they have access to read the files, then the files can be copied.  There is no way to prevent this.

Comment: @MaxVernon TBH, that isnt the same thing.  DVD video files were  encrypted.  However, they were still able to be copied off the DVD.  The user needed the decryption key in order to view the movie.  That key was either in the DVD playback hardware, or in the DVD player software.  Im fairly sure the poster of the question isnt using a proprietary encrypted file format of his design.